# What is the diameter of Lizard Skins Logo and NorthShore grips?

Tags: grips

Those two grips are thicker than usual grips, however so far I cannot find what is the diameter (external) of them (Dual Compound version for both). Maybe we have some owners of them, who would will posting such info here. Thank you in advance.

For reference:

- http://store.lizardskins.com/products/dual-compound-northshore-grip
- http://store.lizardskins.com/products/dual-compound-logo-grip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lizard Skins Lock-on Logo grip is 31.06mm in diameter.

The Lizard Skins Lock-on North Shore grip is 30.94mm in diameter.

Both were measured using a digital caliper, and assuming a small difference in diameter due to texture, they are nominally 31mm diameter grips.

The thinner Lizard skins grips measure approximately 29-30mm, again depending on texture. For instance, the Peaty measured 30mm, and the Charger measured 29mm, but was difficult to get a consistent measurement from because of the type of surface.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Of course this helps, I am only surprised, the manufacturer lists North Shore (L-size) as thicker than Logo (M-size) -- without giving any numbers though -- and now it seems like they are for the same hand size despite LS claims. It was probably more marketing move, than fair information. Thank you a lot!

Comment: It actually feels quite different. I suspect they accont for rubber durometer and (for lack of a better word) the tread pattern on the grip making it feel narrower. The Dually feels quite narrow to me, compared to the Logo grip.

Comment: Dually = dual compound? Logo is also dual compound too. Anyway, pity LS goes for such tricks, I will buy Logo then, because of the patterns and colors choice, I hoped for much difference between different sizes.